# "No" triggers AMAZON.FallbackIntent instead of AMAZON.NoIntent

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have several intents in my skill including some AMAZON built in intents. Three of these are `AMAZON.FallbackIntent`, `AMAZON.NoIntent` and `AMAZON.YesIntent`.
When saying "*yes*" the `AMAZON.YesIntent` is triggered but when I say "*no*" `AMAZON.FallbackIntent` is triggered. So I added "*no*" as an additional utterance to `AMAZON.NoIntent` but still "no" is routed to `AMAZON.FallbackIntent`.

Anyone know why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you try removing `AMAZON.FallbackIntent` from your skill?

Comment: Yes, but if I remove AMAZON.FallbackIntent "No" routes another Intent, never AMAZON.NoIntent.

Comment: What are you using it for? If nothing works, you can try making your own Intent.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a `AMAZON.LITERAL` or `AMAZON.SearchQuery` slot in one of your intents, which kind of interferes with the `AMAZON.NoIntent`. Try removing that intent, `AMAZON.NoIntent` should work fine. A similar issue was discussed in [forum](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/62754/nointent-mapped-to-generic-input-slot.html)

Answer (score 0):

The reason `AMAZON.NoIntent` didn't work was because I had another intent that partially had similar or equal utterances as `AMAZON.NoIntent`. This intent was never matched against which made it a bit more difficult to figure out it was that intent that created this issue.